# Remove space between "" in list of list

Tags: python

```
results = [['my name is', 'my name is "Joe A"', 'my name is "Kim S"', 'my name is "Sam K"', 'my name is "Paul F"']]
```

I tried below, but it appears every space is combined.

```
result = [["".join("".join(sub).split())] for sub in results]
```

My desired result is

```
result = [['my name is', 'my name is "joea"', 'my name is "kims"', 'my name is "samk"', 'my name is "paulf"']]
```

I want to remove any spaces only between "" and lowercase those so that it becomes from "JoeA" to "joea".

Answer (score 5):

You can use regex for your case, which extracts values inside `""` (double quotes) formats them to required form:

```
re.sub(r'"(\w+)(\s(\w+))*"', '"\\1\\3"', x.lower())
```

**Code**:

```
import re

results = [['my name is', 'my name is "Joe A"', 'my name is "Kim S"', 'my name is "Sam K"', 'my name is "Paul F"']]

print([re.sub(r'"(\w+)(\s(\w+))*"', '"\\1\\3"', x.lower()) for x in results[0]])
# ['my name is', 'my name is "joea"', 'my name is "kims"', 'my name is "samk"', 'my name is "paulf"']
```

Comment: what about when it is "Joe A G" and you'd want to get "joeag" and "KIM S F" to "kimsf"? It appears the middle initial gets truncated.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the most pythonic way i.e. list comprehension:

```
desired_output = ['my name is ' + i.split('is')[1].lower().replace(" ", "") for i in results[0] ]

print(desired_output)
['my name is ',
 'my name is "joea"',
 'my name is "kims"',
 'my name is "samk"',
 'my name is "paulf"']
```

Comment: What if 'my name is' is not consistent? For instance, it could be 'her name was' or 'his name was' and could change.